# meaning of 'with just one pass'

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, phrase-usage, phrases

I am transcribing [a podcast](https://www.iheart.com/podcast/105-stuff-you-should-know-26940277/episode/whats-nato-all-about-94894577/) to improve my listening skill.

I can't understand what 'with just one pass' means in this context:

> Josh: So, Chuck, we’re talking about NATO, and if you didn’t know, if
> you didn’t know, we’re in trouble. But if you, the listeners,
> especially the new ones didn’t know, NATO stands for the ‘North
> Atlantic Treaty Organization’ which is the kind of name that you can
> make your eyes glaze over **with just one pass**.

I feel that it means 'immediately' or 'at once'.

Am I wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"glaze over with just one pass" means that someone *bored* just scans the name and feels that the name NATO sounds like a normal name. "with just one pass", specifically, means that the person scans it *quickly*, and does not really come back to read it and understand what it means.

So in a sense, you are sort of right, but read the above paragraph, which I try to make it clearer what it means

*scans* in this context means to read something quickly without much thought